# Pandas: group by date and find smallest n for each date

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe with different dates and a set of IDs per date. I would like to group by date, and then select the 3 smallest rows by a certain column (Amount) for that date. I am trying Pandas functions like below but am getting multiple errors.

This seems like a doable split-apply-combine method - could you please help understand where I am going wrong?

```
df.groupby(['OriginalAmount']).apply(nsmallest(2))
df.groupby(['OriginalAmount']).nsmallest(2).groupby(level='OriginalAmount')
```

Below is a sample dataframe and my desired output when n_smallest equals 2

Dataframe:

```
         Date  ID  Amount
0  2018-01-01  23       5
1  2018-01-01  45      10
2  2018-01-01  56      15
3  2018-01-02  23       5
4  2018-01-02  45      10
5  2018-01-02  99       3
6  2018-01-02  56      15
7  2018-01-03  23       3
8  2018-01-03  45       6
9  2018-01-03  56      19
10 2018-01-03  99       3
```

Desired Output:

```
Date    ID  Amount
1/1/2018    23  5
1/1/2018    45  10
1/2/2018    99  3
1/2/2018    23  5
1/3/2018    23  3
1/3/2018    99  3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are indicating that you want to `groupby` 'Date' but then you are grouping by 'OriginalAmount', which doesn't even appear to be a column in your `DataFrame`.

While you can use `nsmallest`, since you want to subset the original `DataFrame` you can sort the Amount column and then just call .`tail`, (or head) after you form groups based on 'Date'. Sort on the index at the end if you want the original order.

```
df.sort_values('Amount').groupby('Date').head(2).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
          Date  ID  Amount
0   2018-01-01  23       5
1   2018-01-01  45      10
3   2018-01-02  23       5
5   2018-01-02  99       3
7   2018-01-03  23       3
10  2018-01-03  99       3
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Date','Amount']).groupby('Date').head(2)`

Comment: If you use head instead of tail you can drop the ascending=False.

Comment: Hello - sorry for the error, I would like to group by Date and filter the dataframe by the Amount column

Comment: @Z_D this appears to be the solution would you consider accepting?